# Pull image or skip to next cell if empty

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-filter

I am currently using Google Sheets to make a list of videos and thumbnails.
I have various sheets titled: Frying, Stewing, Baking, etc. Within each sheet, there are only two columns which include a thumbnail image and a text link. I would like to create a page which pulls the images from all these sheets into a column.

I have been using:

```
=Baking!A2

=Baking!A3
```

which outputs the thumbnail images that I wanted. The problem with this is, I have to copy/paste the formula each time I add something to a list. Is there a formula which does something similar to:

Check if the sheet1 A3 is empty; if true: skip to sheet2/3/4-100 A3
if not empty: output image.

Here is an example sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1miRsEzIuSWVpwAbcVWWHIp74jVo2nJ8rOE8K61vJ_gQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can solve this with **`ARRAYFORMULA`** like for example:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(Baking!A2:A)
  ```
- if you want to skip empty cells use **`FILTER`** like:

  ```
  =FILTER(Baking!A2:A, Baking!A2:A<>"")
  ```
- if you want to continue with next sheet use **`{}`** brackets to construct range 
  (paste in **A2** cell and drag to the right with a blue square):

  ```
  =FILTER({Frying!A2:A; Baking!A2:A; Stewing!A2:A}, 
          {Frying!A2:A; Baking!A2:A; Stewing!A2:A}<>"")
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- ### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bO1SDDJfeQRjj5Y8Tp_YAC3-G8UE36teqyWikxQ158A/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Im new at this so perhaps im doing something wrong, but when i enter the 3rd formula, i get "Query completed with an empty output."

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1miRsEzIuSWVpwAbcVWWHIp74jVo2nJ8rOE8K61vJ_gQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Diu.Lei answer updated

Comment: Wow, I don't know how or why it works, but it does and it worked better than I ever could have imagined. Thank you so much for your help and time.